# Taking values from a pandas dataframe, modifying them and attaching them in a new dataframe/np.array

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm a bit stuck with the following thing:

I'm trying to take values from a `pandas` dataframe, modifying them and then putting in a new `dataframe`/`np.array`.

In particular the dataframe `df1` looks like this:

```
1.  0   0   ... 0.5   0.5 .. 0
2.  0   0   ...  0     1  .. 0
3.  0.5 0   ...  0    0.5 .. 0
...
```

i.e. I have a lot of zero entries except from some non-zero entries that sum up to one.

What I want to do is taken each row (vector), modifying the zero entries with values taken by the `uniform` distribution taken between some low value and the minimum value between the non-zero entries and then attach the result in a new dataframe or a numpy array.

The result that we can call `df2` should look like this:

```
1.  0.22   0.15   ...   0.5       0.5 ..     0.004
2.  0.7    0.654   ...  0.0567     1  ..     0.45
3.  0.5    0.432   ...  0.354     0.5 ..     0.0432
...
```

I'm trying with the following code:

```
arr = np.array([[]])

for j in range(len(df1)):
    for i in range(103): #103 is the length of these vectors
        if df1.iloc[j][i] == 0:
            arr=np.append([np.random.uniform(low=0.01, high=df1.iloc[j][3:].min()), arr])
        else:
            arr[j][i]= df1.iloc[j][i]
```

What I get is the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-256-141abfd58de1> in <module>
      3 for j in range(len(data)):
      4     for i in range(103):
----> 5         if data.iloc[j][i] == 0:
      6             arr=np.append([np.random.uniform(low=0.01, high=data.iloc[j][3:].min()), arr])
      7         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymatgen\core\composition.py in __eq__(self, other)
    167         #  in the elmap, so checking len enables us to only check one
    168         #  compositions elements
--> 169         if len(self) != len(other):
    170             return False
    171         for el, v in self.items():

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Many thanks,

James

Comment: what is the difference between `df1` and `data` in your code?

Comment: Sorry no difference, as I've just renamed 'data' in the original code with 'df1'. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let’s make a `df1` with 10 rows and 103 columns that has mostly zeros and all rows sum to 1:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({r: {val: np.random.randint(20) for val in np.random.choice(np.arange(103), np.random.randint(2, 5))} for r in range(10)}).T
>>> df1 = df1.div(df1.sum(axis='columns'), axis='index').reindex(columns=np.arange(103)).fillna(0)
```

Let’s check what we did by looking at the data, summing rows, and counting zeros per row:

```
>>> df1
   0    1    2    3    4    5    ...  97   98   99   100  101    102
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.475
6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000
9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000

[10 rows x 103 columns]
>>> df1.sum(axis='columns')
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
8    1.0
9    1.0
dtype: float64
>>> df1.ne(0).sum(axis='columns').astype(int)
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    4
7    3
8    3
9    3
dtype: int64
```

So it seems this respects your specifications for `df1`, now we can start working.

---

First, let’s mask all zeros, so we have a dataframe to extract min non-zero values:

```
>>> df1_nz = df1.mask(df1.eq(0))
>>> df1_nz.min(axis='columns')
0    0.282051
1    0.210526
2    0.181818
3    0.464286
4    0.272727
5    0.100000
6    0.068182
7    0.185185
8    0.050000
9    0.222222
dtype: float64
```

Now from there min we can call `np.uniform` once per row to get a dataframe full of random values, and use these random values to fill in df1 where it’s non-zero:

```
>>> random_vals = pd.DataFrame({
...     r: np.random.uniform(0.01, n, 103) for r, n in df1_nz.min(axis='columns').iteritems()
... }, index=df1.columns).T
>>> df2 = df1_nz.fillna(random_vals)
>>> df2
        0         1         2         3    ...       99        100       101       102
0  0.274312  0.119229  0.200223  0.126925  ...  0.250511  0.076387  0.262691  0.091327
1  0.178858  0.032533  0.171083  0.187775  ...  0.104859  0.141225  0.145604  0.024747
2  0.149279  0.095146  0.067775  0.074993  ...  0.167393  0.109034  0.082226  0.146610
3  0.101093  0.391821  0.266622  0.336723  ...  0.126007  0.438758  0.321557  0.339710
4  0.037873  0.250409  0.123596  0.152685  ...  0.086009  0.190996  0.086574  0.253784
5  0.051473  0.032933  0.085726  0.064984  ...  0.064354  0.050978  0.086429  0.475000
6  0.043807  0.021605  0.049259  0.060036  ...  0.043379  0.052804  0.039904  0.044067
7  0.033173  0.030694  0.178263  0.042904  ...  0.183436  0.019724  0.024167  0.074844
8  0.019714  0.019226  0.028672  0.046260  ...  0.023111  0.042002  0.028637  0.018817
9  0.137686  0.101749  0.127393  0.026675  ...  0.083874  0.197242  0.170042  0.143624

[10 rows x 103 columns]
```

---

If we filter df2 on locations where df1 is non-zero we can see it’s still the same values:

```
>>> df2.where(df1.ne(0)).stack()
0  56     0.410256
   58     0.307692
   77     0.282051
1  13     0.210526
   77     0.789474
2  25     0.181818
   51     0.636364
   92     0.181818
3  19     0.535714
   74     0.464286
4  18     0.454545
   33     0.272727
   91     0.272727
5  38     0.200000
   54     0.225000
   97     0.100000
   102    0.475000
6  7      0.409091
   12     0.068182
   30     0.250000
   73     0.272727
7  18     0.518519
   57     0.185185
   69     0.296296
8  7      0.050000
   40     0.250000
   90     0.700000
9  20     0.259259
   38     0.518519
   89     0.222222
dtype: float64
```

You didn’t explain the `[3:]` so I’ll ignore it but you can reintroduce it in this method with `df1_nz = df1.mask(…)[df1.columns[3:]]`.

Comment: Many thanks Cimbali, I'll read carefully your answer and reach back. The [3:] is just something that I have used to select the columns related to the vectors I've written about (cause the first three columns contain additional information that I don't need). Sorry for the lack of explanation and many thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried your method but in the end the dataframe doesn't get filled with the random_vals, it just remains with all the NaN values in the position of 0s... Could it be a problem with a fact that my columns aren't named with numbers like in your example but they contain string values?

Comment: Yes @JamesArten the column names must match. You can add `index=df1.columns` to the `random _vals` constructor, I’ll add that to the reply.